# Changing value of droplist based on the value of another dropdown list

Tags: jquery

I need to change the selected value on a drop-down list(2) based on the value of the drop-down list(1). I had read a lot of posts but I can't find a solution.

Drop-down list(1)

```
<select name="Active" id="Active" class="imaindatesel">
    <option value="" <?php if (!(strcmp("", $row_SeqUpdate['SeqActive']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Select........</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, $row_SeqUpdate['SeqActive']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Enabled</option>
    <option value="0" <?php if (!(strcmp(0, $row_SeqUpdate['SeqActive']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Disabled</option>   
</select>
```

Drop-down list(2)

```
<select name="Client" class="imaindatesel" id="Client">
    <option value="" <?php if (!(strcmp("", $row_SeqUpdate['ClientName']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Select........</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, $row_SeqUpdate['ClientName']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Enabled</option>
    <option value="0" <?php if (!(strcmp(0, $row_SeqUpdate['ClientName']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Disabled</option>  
</select>
```

Is there some way of doing this using jQuery?

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: add the rendered HTML also add what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do like below:-**

```js
$('#Active').on('change',function(){
   $('#Client').val($('#Active :selected').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Active" id="Active" class="imaindatesel">
    <option value="">Select........</option>
    <option value="1">Enabled</option>
    <option value="0">Disabled</option>   
</select>


<select name="Client" class="imaindatesel" id="Client">
    <option value="">Select........</option>
    <option value="1">Enabled</option>
    <option value="0">Disabled</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will work on this and get back to you. Many thanks.

Comment: @DCJones  glad to help you.:):):)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Client` select according to what is being selected on `Active`

```
$(document).on('change', '#Active', function() {
    $('#Client').val($(this).val());
})
```

[**Live Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/3176/)