# Filling a dropdown list based on another dropdown list in the same html form

Tags: javascript, html, list, dropdown

I have an HTML form with a bunch of  options inside and I'd like to change the values inside those options based on previous user selection:
Let's say I have something like this:

```
<select name="fruit">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="peach">Peach</option>
</select>
```

Based on what the user select there I'd like to have another dropdown list after this one displaying differents values. Something like this if the user select "Apple" in the first dropdown list:

```
<select name="price">
    <option value="3">Apple 1kg 3€</option>
    <option value="5">Apple 2kg 5€</option>
    <option value="7">Apple 3kg 7€</option>
</select>
```

Something like this if he select "Banana":

```
<select name="price">
    <option value="4">Banana 1kg 4€</option>
    <option value="7">Banana 2kg 7€</option>
    <option value="10">Banana 3kg 10€</option>
</select>
```

The value and the text need to change based on the first dropdown list because bananas have a different price than apples and so on. I read a few threads about it but I wasn't really able to understand what I need to make this happen. I never touched ajax before and from what I can read here: [Changing value of droplist based on the value of another dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412353/changing-value-of-droplist-based-on-the-value-of-another-dropdown-list) I need some basic stuff about it. Is it possible to do it just using JavaScript?

Comment: You don't need AJAX for this, but yes, you need JavaScript to detect a change on your first dropdown to fill the second dropdown.

Comment: There are several way you can achieve this using only Js, one way, you can create all the possible price lists, make them all undisplayed, and only shows one of them according to fruit selection. Another way maybe, is to keep the price list empty, and just fill it with values only upon user’s fruit selection. Try those options and post back if you struggle with coding them.

Comment: But first, you'll have to defined your pricing for each option, in a JavaScript object or array.

Comment: First question: Where do you get the prices from?

Comment: @HerrSerker I just started coding so I am completly unaware of how to do this. I'm assuming your question is to know if I have a DB or not. No I don't right now but I could make it based on your answers to the question. Since I'd like to learn, let's say I have a database with those values inside:
`id_fruit   fruit_name   price_1kg    price_2kg   price_3kg`

Comment: Let's assume you have some kind of ressource (no matter what programming language used), which returns a JSON with the prices, It could even be a static resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using an object to hold the values and their associated dropdown's descriptions. In order to do this, you firstly need to add an event listener to your dropdown so that it will detect a change when you pick a new fruit. Using the change event listener, you can retrieve the value of the option which was selected using `this.value`.

Using the `value` from the option selected, you can proceed to get its associated dropdown's values from the object called `prices` (this will return an array). Once you've gotten this array, you can loop through it and "build" a string of HTML using `.reduce()` to place as the options for the `price` select tag. Once you've built this string, you can append it inside the select tag using `.innerHTML` which "converts" your HTML string to DOM objects (real elements rather than just text):

```js
const prices = {"apple":[{value:3,desc:"Apple 1kg 3&euro;"},{value:5,desc:"Apple 2kg 5&euro;"},{value:7,desc:"Apple 3kg 7&euro;"}],
             "banana":[{value:3,desc:"Banana 2kg 3.5&euro;"},{value:5,desc:"Banana 4kg 7&euro;"},{value:7,desc:"Banana 5kg 11&euro;"}],
             "peach":[{value:3,desc:"Peach 1.5kg 3&euro;"},{value:5,desc:"Peach 3kg 6&euro;"},{value:7,desc:"Peach 4kg 7&euro;"}]}

const price = document.querySelector('[name=price]');
document.querySelector('[name=fruit]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  price.innerHTML = prices[this.value].reduce((acc, elem) => `${acc}<option value="${elem.value}">${elem.desc}</option>`, "");
});
```

```html
<select name="fruit">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="peach">Peach</option>
</select>
<br />
<select name="price">
  <option value="3">Apple 1kg 3€</option>
  <option value="5">Apple 2kg 5€</option>
  <option value="7">Apple 3kg 7€</option>
</select>
```

If you don't feel comfortable using `.reduce()` you can use a regular for loop instead:

```
...  
let options = "";
for(const obj of prices[this.value]) {
  options += '<option value="' +obj.value +'">' +obj.desc +'</option>';
}
price.innerHTML = options;
...
```

Comment: I think I got what you are saying, however is not fully working for me, probably I have done something wrong (I'm sure I have done something wrong). Could you please post a full example of it? Including the `script` tag? This is my very first attemp with js. Only used php/sql since today

Comment: @TheNoobUser https://jsfiddle.net/jng3a0mh/  <--- Notice the position of the scrit tags

Comment: Parson Thank you so much. I got my mistake now, I was adding the script before the actual list. Now it works and I will have to read more about js. Thanks a lot and have a nice day

Comment: @TheNoobUser If you wish to keep your javascript in the `<head>` of your HTML file, you can add `window.onload = function() {// code here}`. https://jsfiddle.net/jng3a0mh/1/

Comment: No worries, the reason as to why it wasn't working was because the javascript was running before the entire page had loaded. This means that when the javascript does `document.getElementsByName('fruit')` it can't find the element with the name `fruit` as it hasn't loaded in yet. So, we can fix this by putting the javascript at the bottom of the page so everything is loaded before we get to the javascrit or we can use the `.onload` event, which will fire the javascript once the entire page has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attached solution using element creation and onchange event with JQuery

```js
// First we initialize a variable with the fruits and their prices per kg
fruitPrices = {'apple':[3, 5, 6], 'banana':[4, 7, 10]}

// Listen to changes in selected fruit
$('#fruit-selector').on('change', function(element) {
  // Clearing the price selector and getting the selected fruit
  $('#price-selector').empty()
  chosenFruit = this.value;
  
  // For each price in the fruitPrices for this fruit
  for (fruitIndex in fruitPrices[chosenFruit]) {
      // Get the price and create an option element for it
      price = fruitPrices[chosenFruit][fruitIndex];
      price_option = '<option>{0} {1}kg {2}$<option>'.replace('{0}', chosenFruit).replace('{1}', fruitIndex + 1).replace('{2}', price);
      // Add the option to the price selector
      $('#price-selector').append(price_option)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='fruit-selector' name="fruit">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="peach">Peach</option>
</select>

<select id='price-selector' name="price">

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.clear();

(function() {

  var fruitsField = document.querySelector('[name=fruits]')
  var amountField = document.querySelector('[name=amount]')
  var json = {};


  onReady(loadJson);
  fruitsField.addEventListener('change', populateAmount)


  function onReady(callback) {
    if (
      document.readyState === "complete" ||
      (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll)
    ) {
      callback();
    } else {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    }  
  }

  function getSelectedFruit() {
    return fruitsField.value;
  }

  function populateFruits() {
    clearOptions(fruitsField)
    fruits = json.fruits
    for (var i in fruits) {
      addOption(fruitsField, i, fruits[i])
    }
  }

  function populateAmount() {
    clearOptions(amountField)
    var fruit = getSelectedFruit()
    fruits = json.fruits
    prices = json.prices[fruit]
    for (var i in prices) {
      addOption(amountField, i, fruits[fruit] + " " + i + "kg " + prices[i] + "€")
    }
  }

  
  // Load a json resource and start the fruit process
  function loadJson() {
    fetch('//api.jsonbin.io/b/5bf5645b746e9b593ec0e8b5')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      json = response
      populateFruits()
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    })
  }


  // function loadJson() {
  //   var j = '{"fruits":{"apple":"Apples","banana":"Bananas","peach":"Peaches"},"prices":{"apple":{"1":3,"2":5,"3":7},"banana":{"1":4,"2":7,"3":10},"peach":{"1":5,"2":9,"3":13}}}'
  //   json = JSON.parse(j)
  //   populateFruits()
  // }

  function addOption(select, value, text) {
    var option = document.createElement('option')
    option.setAttribute('value', value)
    option.textContent = text
    select.appendChild(option)
  }

  function clearOptions(select) {
    var children = select.children
    var childrenToRemove = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < children.length; i++) {
      childrenToRemove.push(children[i])
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < childrenToRemove.length; i++) {
      select.removeChild(childrenToRemove[i])
    }
  }

}())
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="fruits" size="4">
    <option value="0">Select Fruit</option>
  </select>
  <select name="amount" size="4">
    <option value="0" >Select Amount</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Choose an ice cream flavor:
  <select class="ice-cream" name="ice-cream">
    <option value="">Select One …</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="sardine">Sardine</option>
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
  </select>
</label>

<div class="result"></div>

const selectElement = document.querySelector('.ice-cream');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const result = document.querySelector('.result');
  result.textContent = `You like ${event.target.value}`;
});
```